# How Cordapps are getting deployed with corda.jar while running corda nodes?

Tags: corda

We are defining the nodes configuration in build.gradle.

After running the gradle deployNodes task, based on the configuration in build directory/nodes- Folders are getting created in their names.

Each node is having the following files:

1. Corda.jar
2. network-parameters
3. persistence.mv.db
4. node.conf
5. certificates
6. drivers
7. logs
8. cordapps

These the following questions I have,

1. What is the runnodes.jar does - means how corda.jar is started and how cordapps are deployed on top of that?
2. If I change the node.conf, then runnodes will it affect the node.conf or Do I need to build the corda.jar again ?
3. Where the p2paddress of other nodes are shared with each node.

Suppose If I want to deploy the nodes in different EC2 instances, Do I need to mention the p2paddress with correct ec2 ipaddress of each nodes on build.gradle or I can do it dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

1. `runnodes` goes to each node's folder and starts it by running the Corda JAR (by running something like `java -jar corda.jar`). When the Corda JAR starts, it scans the `cordapps` folder for CorDapps and loads them into the node
2. If you stop a node and modify the `node.conf` file, the changes will apply when you next run the node. There is no need to redeploy
3. It depends:

   - If you're running in development mode, the bootstrapper is run when you first deploy the nodes to copy each node's `nodeInfo` (a file containing its name, public keys, addresses, etc.) to the other nodes. If you modify one of the nodes' addresses in its `node.conf` file, you need to re-run the bootstrapper. See the instructions [here](https://docs.corda.net/setting-up-a-corda-network.html#bootstrapping-the-network)
   - If you're running outside of development mode, you need to provide a network map server (as described [here](https://docs.corda.net/network-map.html#network-map)) that will distribute information on the network's nodes to each node

Comment: Thanks a lot Joel.On 3rd point, in this case if I'm developing an consortium application. I need to build the bootstrapper function in one place like the development cannot happen decentralized way. To more clear first time we have created the corda jar, cordapps and distributed to different organisations. They have deployed in corresponding cloud instances. One day some organization need to change the p2paddress of their node, how to update this data to other two nodes? Thanks in advance.